# Use previous response in subsequent concatMap handlers

Tags: rxjs

I have a variable number of urls to request, and properties from the response of each request are used partly as the input for the next - I have a config of objects with the urls and properties to pluck

The `concatMap` operator works well as part of a stream e.g. `from(urls).pipe(concatMap(...))` for making the calls in sequence

I'm wondering is there a way to use the response of each `xhr` or `rxjs/ajax` call that's made within the `concatMap` as the input for the next call?

I can get around this with an external `ReplaySubject` to store/retrieve the responses as needed, but thought there may be an rxjs operator approach for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's interesting case. Btw there is a solution, not with RxJS only, but you can use it:

```
const requests = [url1, url2, url3];

const combineRequests = requests.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  return prev.pipe(switchMap(prevData => curr.pipe(map(res => { ... you have previous data here in the pipe }))))
}, of(null));

combineRequests.subscribe();
```

You can modify request the same way and not only use previous data in pipes.

Comment: I had to read and re-read that a few times Haven't seen observables built up in that fashion before:`of().pipe().pipe()..`

Comment: That's not a bad and you get multiple request interaction.